# Alternative to 'load more' thumbnail pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Is there any simple code for 'load more' pagination, I mean without plugin, I just saw it http://www.inserthtml.com/demo/scroll-pagination/ , but I prefer look for a simple code for this task. I need the load more button works after I scroll 4 grid row that each of them has 4 column, in other words is 16pcs li or div and then it will load the next content below previous grid. Does anyone know to gain this; does it need ajax ? 
Thanks.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2qvtjyw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this Tutorial and Yes you Need AJAX

[insert Html Tutorial](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/)